# pass text box value as parameter to action ? MVC

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have to save method on page master and detail like this

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Code_Main", System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Main_Code, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = ViewBag.Main_Code } })
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Main_CodeDD, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = ViewBag.Main_CodeDD } })

  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CType_D, new { htmlAttributes = new { @Value = ViewBag.CType_D } })



    <button id="cmd_Add_List" type="image" tabindex="4" onclick="" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "Code_Main")  '">
                                        Save
                                    </button>

}
```

on this save click i save the value that is passed to create action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
    {
    //sucess     
       return view();
     }
```

now on another click button i want to save other feilds like top 2 **Main_Code and Main_CodeDD** 
SO

```
  <button id="cmdsave_2" style="background-image: url(@Url.Content("~/Images/save.gif")); background-color: white; border: none; height: 32px; width: 65px;"                                                                                               type="submit" tabindex="4" 
 onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("save_Main", "Code_Main" , new { 
 Main_ID = document.getElementById('Main_ID').value , Main_CodeDD = 
 document.getElementById('Main_CodeDD').value , cmbAType_SD = 
 document.getElementById('cmbAType_SD').value , cmbCType_SD = 
 document.getElementById('cmbCType_SD').value})  />
```

this button click not invoking

```
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult  Save_Main(string Main_ID  ,string Main_Code  ,   string Main_CodeDD , string cmbAType_SD  , string cmbCType_SD )
    {

        try
        {



        }
        catch { }

        return View("Index");
    }
```

but create action called can any body tell me how to invoke different action and passing parameter to it

Comment: by master detail i mean page have 2 save button ...

Comment: You're mixing server-side code and client-side code.  It doesn't work that way at all.  Surely the compiler is telling you that these things are not defined.  Why are you using all of this `onclick="location.href=...` in the first place?  Just have the button post the form, then you get the form elements automatically.

Comment: but want to call different action on 2 save button click

Comment: i have 2 save button want to save different textbox values so  i have 4 operation 2 save update for main and 2 save update for child

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the "Onclick" attribute of submit button and it will call the function with the values of textboxes. 
location.href will not post the data rather it will look for [httpget] create action in the controller

Answer (score 0):

Your button doesn't submit form values, but just redirecting on provided URL.

you have to use

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit form values" />
```

The line where you starting to generate the form have names of action and controller, so you don't need to provide URL in submit element.